# What is the difference between horizon of expectation and expectation?

Tags: terminology, theory

I'm studying reader-response theory and wonder what is the difference between [horizon of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_of_expectation) and a simple [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_(epistemic)). In my understanding, the horizon of expectation is just expectation. It just discusses more about cultural code and other texts from the reader's period/generation. Is that correct? And how is horizon relevant here? What not call it as system of expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizon of expection(s) (German: *Erwartungshorizont*) goes beyond a 
single reader's expectations. According to Hans Robert Jauss, the 
evaluation of a literary work requires a reconstruction of the "horizon 
of expectation(s)" that the author's contemporaries would have brought to 
that work. This "horizon of expectations" refers to the set of 
expectations and assumptions witch which readers from a specific generation 
and a specific culture read literary works. (Readers are not 
necessarily constantly aware of the entire set of expectations while reading.)
Obviously, Shakespeare's contemporaries would have approached *Hamlet* 
with totally different expectations than early 21st-century readers or 
theatre goers. For example, theatre was not as highly regarded as a 
genre as today, and Elizabethans would have been much more familiar 
with the conventions of [revenge 
tragedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge_tragedy).

For Jauss, each of a work's "receptions" by successive generations of 
readers is a valid object of study; he described this succession of 
receptions as a “continuous establishing and altering of horizons”.
A specific literary work may expand one's (aesthetic) horizon (in which case it is 
valuable) or not (e.g. [formula 
fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_fiction)).

Sources:

- Nasrullah Mambrol: [Key Theories of Hans Robert Jauss](https://literariness.org/2018/02/01/key-theories-of-hans-robert-jauss/) 
  , 01.02.2018.
- Muhammad Naeem: [Terry Eagleton – Author, Text and the 
  Reader](https://neoenglish.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/terry-eagleton-author-text-and-the-reader/), 10.12.2010.
- [Hans Robert 
  Jauß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Robert_Jau%C3%9F) (Wikipedia, 
  German).
- [Horizon of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_of_expectation) (Wikipedia)